# Wait for Function to complete and then return a value

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I have this function `Offline.check();` , which takes 1 seconds to execute..So below function is not waiting for it and it always return false on first time.I used set time out..but thats always returning null.

```
  function checkstats()

    {

    Offline.check(); // This returns Offline.state=up  or down and it takes 1 seconds to complete.

    if(Offline.state=="up")
    {
    return true;
    }

    else
    {
    return false;
    }

    }

var a = checkstats();
```

Comment: what does your Offline.check() function do? Is there an asynchronous operation there? Most likely you have to pass a callback for asynchronous operation and implement the rest of your code in callback.

Comment: yea asynchronous operation going on in that.

Comment: Offline.check() is external js .. so i cant add callback to that asynchronous..any other way to solve this ?

Comment: Perhaps call offline.check (on your html page or loaded js file), append the rest of your code dynamically in a script tag..

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you could set a callback function with `Offline.check`, but I understand it is external, so that won't work.

You can use a timeout to wait for `Offline.state` to get set, but then you'll need to do any actions involving the variable `a` asynchronously too:

```
function checkstats(callBack){  // checkstats() now takes a callback
    Offline.check();  // Start Offline.check() as usual

    setTimeout(function(){  // Set a timeout for 1 second
        if(Offline.state=="up")  // After 1 second, check Offline.state as usual
        {
            callBack(true);  // ...but we call the callback instead of returning
        }
        else
        {
            callBack(false);  // ...but we call the callback instead of returning
        }
    }, 1000);
}

checkstats(function(a){ // This anonymous function is the callback we're using
    // Now you can use "a" normally
});
```

If you're not sure that `Offline.check()` will take *exactly 1 second*, you can use an interval instead of a timeout, and try every second for, say, 5 seconds:

```
function checkstats(callBack){
    Offline.check();

    var attempt = 0, maxAttempts = 5;
    var checkStatsInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(++attempt > maxAttempts){
            // Ran out of attempts, just give up
            clearInterval(checkStatsInterval);
            alert('Waited '+maxAttempts+' seconds for Offline data. Giving up!');
            return;
        }
        if(Offline.state){
            clearInterval(checkStatsInterval);

            // It's loaded! Now confidently check Offline.state
            if(Offline.state=="up")
            {
                callBack(true);
            }
            else
            {
                callBack(false);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}

checkstats(function(a){
    // Now you can use "a" normally
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asynchronous JavaScript to address the issue. There are several ways of implementing asynchronous behaviour in JavaScript. You can use Callbacks, Listeners or Promises.

Anyway, if you are certain that it only takes 1 second, setTimeout in a callback function and allow `Offline.check()` to complete. (If it's external or lazy to implement async there)

```
doOfflineCheck(function(){
    if(Offline.state=="up")
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
});

function doOfflineCheck(cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
    Offline.check();
    },1000);
}
```