# How to return a value after waiting for function completion in node.js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, return

I have a function

```
function getDevices() {
    var devices = [];
    /* code that checks lan for devices and pushes to device array */
    /* this is done with an event emitter so its occurs as devices are found */
    setTimeout(5000, function() {/*stop searching for devices*/});
    return devices;
}
```

How do i get the function get devices to return all the devices after the 5 seconds?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228291/wait-for-function-to-complete-and-then-return-a-value): which uses callbacks but it doesn't end up returning the function. Id like to have a global variable that i can assign the result of getDevices() to without having to access the global variable inside the getDevices function

Comment: Right now, because of async, this function just returns `[]` because it skips all the way to the return

Comment: You're using `setTimeout` incorrectly too. `setTimeout(fn, delay, arg0, arg1, arg2, ...argN)`